# A smooth structure alternative to the Identity map on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds, surfaces

Assume that we have an open subset $P \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $P =\{ \mathbf{p}: a < ||\mathbf{p}||_{2} < b \}$. $P$ can be covered by a single chart, which is the identity. This chart can be shown to be homeomorphic, smooth and has a smooth inverse; therefore, it is smooth. Since all of $P$ is covered by this one smooth chart, we have a smooth structure on $P$.

My question is, if I wanted to use more than one chart, what choices would I use?

I thought of the exponential map: chart 1: $re^{i\theta}$ where $a < r< b$ and $0 < \theta < 2\pi$ and chart 2: $re^{i\theta}$ where $a < r< b$ and $-\pi < \theta < \pi$, but it does not map to $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm really confused that complex plane has 2 dimensions and yet the exponential map results in a single value. Which is why I cannot justify using this map for $P$, but can justify it as a chart for a circle.
Please advise!

Comment: Not clear what you mean by “it doesn’t map to $\mathbb R^2?”$ Your polar coordinates approach is good. Let $$U_1=\{(u,v)\mid u\in (\ln a,\ln b), b\in(0,2\pi)\}.$$ Then $\phi(u,v)=(e^u\cos v,e^u\sin v)$ is one chart.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews- What I meant was: when we use $re^{i\theta}$ as a chart for $S^1$, we map from $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^1$; or am I misinterpreting? Thank you, I will try what you suggested and come back with more questions for you. :)

Comment: Each open subset $P$ of $\mathbb R^2$ has a canonical smooth structure given by the atlas having one element $id_P$.